# How do I save QRcode as image in C

Tags: c, bitmap, qr-code

I am using libqrenode for generating QRcodes in C. I would like then save generated QRcode as bitmap. How to do that? Can anyone give me a piecie of code?

Comment: If the library name is a typo and you meant [qrencode](https://fukuchi.org/works/qrencode/), its readme suggests it contains sample code to save as PNG, which is a bitmap file type.

Answer (score 3):

The QRencode library cannot export as a bitmap directly. what you need to do is the following

```
QRcode my_qr;  //this is the code you want to print

for (int h=0; h<my_qr.height; h++)
  for (int w=0; w<my_qr.width; w++) {
    if (my_qr.data[h*my_qr.width+w]%2 == 1) printf("#"); // black pixel
    else printf(" "); // white pixel
  }
  printf("\n");
```

Of course this will result in simple text, not in a bitmap, but this text could easily be imported as XPM image or you can extend the above code slightly, by prepending the correct header for a bitmap.

The library itself contains a test/example for writing the QRCode in a PNG file. You can view it here: https://github.com/fukuchi/libqrencode/blob/1b565c7b599029818fc596e7da4371a3083da36c/tests/create_frame_pattern.c It uses the approach I explained above.

Comment: Use ⬛ and ⬜ for the black and white pixels and you can create a photo scannable QR code from a string